# d3sparql force graph - nodes not connected

Tags: d3.js, graph, sparql, ontology

I've been trying to use d3sparql to produce a force-directed graph based on my ontology. 
I have this data that I'm trying to show in the graph :

```
---------------------------------------------------
scname              |      pname       | author   |
---------------------------------------------------
Prunus Serrulata    | Sheraton Cherry  | John Doe |
Ailanthus Altissima | Chinese Sumac    | Jane Doe |
Acca Sellowiana     | Pineapple Guava  | John Doe |
---------------------------------------------------
```

As we can see, there are two instances that have the same author, John Doe.

But in the graph, both nodes are not linked to each other. And eventhough there is supposed to be 3 nodes of scname, pname, and author, but in the graph there are only nodes of pname and author.

[image: screenshot]

EDIT : What I am trying to do is something like this :

[image: example]

Does it have something to do with my owl file since all 3 instances have its own data properties?
And why does the graph only show 2 nodes instead of all 3 nodes?

EDIT :

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3sparql.js"></script>
    <script>
    function exec() {
      var endpoint = d3.select("#endpoint").property("value")
      var sparql = d3.select("#sparql").property("value")
      d3sparql.query(endpoint, sparql, render)
    }
    function render(json) {
      var config = {
        "charge": -500,
        "distance": 50,
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 750,
        "selector": "#result"
      }
      d3sparql.forcegraph(json, config)
    }
    function toggle() {
      d3sparql.toggle()
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="query" style="margin: 10px">
      <h1>d3forcegraph</h1>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <label>SPARQL endpoint:</label>
        <div class="input-append">
          <input id="endpoint" class="span5" value="http://localhost:3030/plantont/query" type="text">
          <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="exec()">Query</button>
          <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="toggle()"><i id="button" class="icon-chevron-up"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <textarea id="sparql" class="span9" rows=15>

        PREFIX podb: <http://localhost:8080/plantdb/ontology/plantont#>
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

        SELECT  ?scname ?pname ?author
        WHERE
             { ?sub podb:scientificName ?scname .
               ?sub podb:plantName ?pname .
               ?sub podb:hasTaxon ?tax .
               ?tax podb:scientificNameAuthorship ?author

  }

      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unlikely anyone can solve this for you without an example of what you're actually doing. It might also help to tag this question with d3.

Comment: already add some more details.